# Disable input fields within iFrame without Javascript

Tags: html, iframe, disabled-input

I know that you can disable an input field like this:

```
<input disabled></input>
```

But is there a simple way to disable all the inputs within an iFrame a similar way?  Like this:

```
<iframe src="/foo" disabled></iframe>
```

Comment: Even if it's an internal source?

Comment: If you don't want to change the markup or use Javascript either...

Comment: I just thought there was a way to add something to the iframe since I saw similar posts using javascript

Comment: Check on the W3C documentation and you can see the attributes/properties available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no answers have been satisfactory (or they just didn't answer the correct question), so I am answering my own.

The answer I've found from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) on the properties/attributes has led me to believe it is impossible.  Since I was using an iframe from a source I could modify, I fixed what I needed to there, but it would have been a much cleaner and DRYer solution if this were possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can affect and iframe from an outside source

Comment: What if it's an internal source

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to disable an iframe but you can use a div over the iframe to avoid user interaction

```
<div id="blank" style="display:none; position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:600px; height:400px;">
```

changing top left width and height with the coordinates and size of your iframe

and when you want to disable iframe

```
document.getElementById("blank").style.display="block";
```

if you want to disable iframe since load just change display none to block on the original div

I hope this helps :)

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use Javascript.

Comment: As it says in the post you can use style="display:block" in the original div and you dont need to use javascript

Comment: Your solution will "disable" the whole iFrame, not just the inputs within it.

Comment: Solved my problem :) Have my +1